# Use a list of strings to replace a sql parameter printing the whole file for each replacement

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, sql

I have a txt file with string values in a single column :

`File.txt`

```
A

B
.
.
.
Z
```

I have a `sql` script with a variable called `'parameter'`.

`script.sql`

```
declare @var varchar(255)
set @var = 'parameter'
select * from table_name where column = @var
go
```

I want to read the file line by line and use each line to replace parameter in the sql , print out all `sql` statements to a file (and eventually run that sql)

I am open to use `perl` or `python`, but a simple shell solution would be much appreciated.

E.g. something like: `cat file.txt |sed "s/parameter/$0/" script.sql`

Expected output for e.g. `A` and `B` :

NewFile

```
declare @var varchar(255)
set @var = 'A'
select * from table_name where column = @var
go
declare @var varchar(255)
set @var = 'B'
select * from table_name where column = @var
go
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash way with the pitfall to call sed everytime (performance penalty applies):

```
while read -r line;do
  sed -r "s/parameter/$line" script.sql >>newfile.sql
done <file.txt
```

another bash way:

```
old="$(<script.sql)"
while read -r ln;do
echo "${old/parameter/$ln}" >>newfile.sql
done <file.txt
```

The awk way:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;last=FNR;next}{for (i=1;i<=last;i++) \
print (a[i] ~ /^set @var/)?gensub(/parameter/,$0,"g",a[i]):a[i] >>"new.sql"}' script.sql file.txt
```

[awk test online here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNEd6Qk9tbkNlUFk) (press execute button above code )

Comment: pardon my naivete but what are variables NR and FNR ?

Comment: Are awk built-in variables used for Number Record (NR) along all files, and File Number Records (FNR) for file under process (resets on every file read next). The check NR==FNR means do the {action} for the first file only

Comment: @user221826 one more bash alternative

Comment: It works perfectly. However I am still unable to understand the first line , 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;last=FNR;next}{for (i=1;i<=last;i++) \

Comment: @user221826 - the two-liner is for readability - don't mix them: the `for` loop is executed only when reading the second input file; the stuff that precedes it is executed only when reading the first input file

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I got it , just one part why does the counter i start with 1 ? Is there no a[0] record for awk?

Comment: In awk all arrays are associative.No matter if you apply a [1],a [0] or a ["george"]. We use to start from 1 for easy human reading and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
read -d '' -r SQL < script.sql
while IFS= read -r par; do printf '%s\n' "${SQL/\'parameter\'/\'$par\'}"; done < File.txt
```